# How to retrieve the p-values from a zero inflated regression in R?

Tags: r

The summary output of my zero inflated regression includes p-values:

```
    Call:
zeroinfl(formula = Walk ~ WalkIndex, data = walkadata, subset = offset(Total_commuters), dist = "negbin")

Pearson residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max

-0.56308 -0.43333 -0.40561 -0.07236 72.95178 

Count model coefficients (negbin with log link):

             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  

(Intercept)  2.441129   0.008827  276.54   <2e-16 ***

WalkIndex    0.058598   0.001192   49.15   <2e-16 ***

Log(theta)  -0.085677   0.007679  -11.16   <2e-16 ***

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):

             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    

(Intercept)  0.997773   0.010048   99.31   <2e-16 ***

WalkIndex   -0.052690   0.001392  -37.86   <2e-16 ***

---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Theta = 0.9179 

Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 21 

Log-likelihood: -3.902e+05 on 5 Df
```

I can save the coefficients into variables but can't find the p-values in the list.

Any suggestions?

Comment: assign the model fit to a variable (say `fit`), and then call `str(fit)` to see its structure. you will be able to interactively find out how to select the part you're looking for. you might also want to use `str(summary(fit))`. for example to get the p-vals from a `lm()` fit: `summary(lm(iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Sepal.Width))$coefficients[,4]`

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, but unfortunately, the fit of the zeroinfl() doesn't include the p-values.